# Noob jQuery "$" function return question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="priceperperson1" name="priceperperson1" />
<input type="text" name="personsvalue1" class="countme" readonly="readonly" />
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('div.pricerow input.countme').each(function(){ 
var id = this.name.substr(this.name.length-1);
alert($('input#priceperperson'+id));
this.value = parseInt($('priceperperson'+id).value) * parseInt($('countpersons'+id).value); 
});
});
```

Shortened as possible. All I've in alert is "Object"... Value is NaN. I've tried to "parseInt" on id. I've tried:

```
$('[name=priceperperson'+id+']');
$('priceperperson'+id);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you add the line: alert('input#priceperperson'+id); ? Are you positive that the string is being formed as you want it to be?

Comment: your code may contain errors !
id = lenght 1 OK 
if id lenght > 1 ?? possible exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are retrieving jQuery objects when you do the `$(..)`

To get the value (**string**) use the `.val()` method.

so

```
alert( $('input#priceperperson'+id).val() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably put the `$` in the function definition.

I'm guessing it's causing the `$` variable to be re-defined, in the function -- and not point to the jQuery's `$()` function anymore.

I'm thinking about this one :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Try using, instead :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are looping through jquery objects, I believe you have to use:

$(this).attr('name'); *instead of* this.name

also, to call values from objects you have to use $.val() or $.attr('attributename');

```
// Shortcut for doc ready
$(function() 
{ 
 // Loop through values
 var id = $(this).attr('name');

 alert($('input#priceperperson' + id).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps looking for [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)?

```
this.val(parseInt($('priceperperson'+id).val()));
```

Answer (score 0):

> All I've in alert is "Object"... Value
>   is NaN. I've tried to "parseInt"

Try giving a base to `parseInt`:

```
parseInt(variable, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes... to get the value of a jQuery object you must use `.val()` method, not `.value`.

Then, the parseInt() requires, as second parameter, the radix. Something like:

```
...
this.value = parseInt($('priceperperson'+id).val(), 10) * parseInt($('countpersons'+id).val(), 10); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

your code may contain errors

your code 
id = lenght 1 OK
if id lenght > 1 ?? possible exception

priceperperson1 to priceperperson_1

```
# option # proposal

<input type="text" id="priceperperson_1" name="priceperperson_1" /> // => use "_"
<input type="text" name="personsvalue_1" class="countme" readonly="readonly" />


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.pricerow input.countme').each(function(){ 
        var id = this.name.split("_")[1]; // => get array value 
        this.value = parseInt($('[name=priceperperson_'+id+']').value()) *parseInt($('[name=countpersons='+id+']').value()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Impossible - only 4 elements.